# Breeze and Unity not working together in an ASP.NET WebApi application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, unity-container, breeze

I’m trying out Breeze.js framework in a sample .NET WebApi app. I had a couple of controllers setup working and using Unity.WebApi to inject app's unit of work.

I am using Entity Framework 6, so I installed Breeze using "Breeze Client and Server - Javascript client with ASP.NET Web API 2 and Entity Framework 6" package (id: Breeze.WebApi2.EF6). After doing that I added the BreezeController, but now my app breaks giving me the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Source Error:

```
Line 15:             GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
Line 16:                 new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
Line 17:         }
Line 18: 
Line 19:         private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
```

Googling and StackOverflowing this error yields results related to different circumstances, so those where not of great help. However the error comes from the Unity's Bootstrapper file, so I removed Unity and after that my Breeze controller started working. Put Unity back - it breaks again

Breeze controller:

```
public class BreezeController : ApiController
{
    readonly EFContextProvider<DataContext> _contextProvider = 
        new EFContextProvider<DataContext>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Category> Categories()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Categories;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a Unity problem. There's a strong likelihood that the version of Unity that you installed has not be updated for the most recent VS2013 releases. Please check with Microsoft about that.

You can make some progress on your own by writing a test case that has no Breeze at all. From a clean slate, create a Web API project. Then add Unity. Then create a do-nothing class and try to inject it. I'll bet that fails. If not, add the breeze package and try again.

Comment: I think that's what I've done. I've started a project from scratch, added a couple of controllers, setup Unity and things were working and only when I installed Breeze it broke.

Comment: Maybe because Breeze also updated the version of WebApi that I was using. I'll try to check that.

Comment: Worth checking. The last few weeks have been hell trying to get all the different components on the same page. So much for the end of "DLL Hell" :D.  Appreciate your patience

Comment: Unity.WebApi seems to be going thru some updates as well, so hoping to see things stabilize soon. But probably I'm missing something. Breeze and Unity both seem to work separate from each other but when I put them together some inconsistency appears and that error comes up. But thanks for your help, I'll try again later. There is definitely a lot of DLLs to juggle.